# How to get the json data from this link

Tags: jquery, json

http://just4dummy.com/Haggle/index.php/api/haggle/bills/user/1/format/json

How to console the data in the firefox from this link.

How to get the json data from this link and use it inside the html tags.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: if I could console the data in the firefox I'd be rich by now

Comment: Just use `$.getJSON`.. but what do you mean with `use it inside the html` tags?

Comment: Does the domain it allow cross domain requests?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ - If you're doing a cross-domain request, you'll need to look at JSONP.

Comment: i mean i want to list the json data in the html tags

Comment: @BabuArumugam list in HTML tags..? You mean create a Table out of it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use JSONP to be able to access it cross domain.

```
$.getJSON('http://just4dummy.com/Haggle/index.php/api/haggle/bills/user/1/format/jsonp?callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I changed the "json" to "jsonp", and added "?callback=?" to the url.  It's up to the server to support JSONP, not all servers do, this one just happened to support it.

The returned data is an array of objects, you can read it like this:

```
$.each(data, function(){
    console.log(this.account);
});
```

From, here you can easily add the data to an HTML table.

Comment: great it worked for me to see the values in console. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.getJSON('http://just4dummy.com/Haggle/index.php/api/haggle/bills/user/1/format/json', function(data) {...});
```

Comment: i tried with console with in this function and it does not showed me any thing

Comment: I think it is because of Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: So how this can be achievable