# Origin https://site.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. using JSON

Tags: drupal-7, cross-domain

This is the first time that I encountered such problem, I have this code which came from the answers from this site and trying to experiment what the output is gonna be.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/lookup.json?screen_name=episod,twitterapi', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

So when I run it, it shows like this, the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". How can I fix this problem? Like allowing to get data from other location.

[image]

Any solution for this stuff? I'm using drupal 7, I might as well say it because it might be relevant to my problem though.

I saw this questions but, never helped and some of it seems vauge.

[XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

[How to get the json data from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046691/how-to-get-the-json-data-from-this-link)

https://drupal.org/node/1937756

https://drupal.org/project/services_accept_origin

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API does not support CORS requests, you have to use JSONP instead. You can trigger a JSONP request by adding the `callback` query parameter. Here is an example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/lookup.json?screen_name=episod,twitterapi",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Twitter's documentation for the `callback` parameter can be found here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/things-every-developer-should-know